# Loading the output of the layers from the pretrained checkpoint (.bin)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, bert-language-model, word-embedding

I have a PyTorch model with the following architecture: `BERT -> dropout -> classifier -> loss_function`. I have fine-tuned the model on my dataset and used the predictions. Now I want to access the output of the BERT model before the classifier layer. I want to use them as my sentence embedding.

**My question is**, 1) how do I store the output of each of the 12 hidden layers for my input?
2) Which of the fields, `output.dense.weight`, `output.dense.bias`, `output.LayerNorm.weight` `output.LayerNorm.bias` I should use?

---

**Here is what I already tried**

I created a BERT model from pretrained `bert_base`, and used `model.load_state_dict(ckpt)`. Now I can make predictions with this model:

```
tokenized_text = np.array(tokenizer.encode(text))
padded_text = np.zeroes(50)[:tokenized_text.shape[0]] = tokenized_text
input_ids = torch.tensor(padded_text).reshape(1,50)
input_ids = input_ids.type(torch.long)

model(input_ids)
```

The above code will give me a `[1,50,768]` and a `[1, 768]` tensor.

---

**Additional information**

When I load the checkpoint with `torch.load` and I have access to the following vectors `bert.embeddings.*` and `bert.encoder.layer.*`.
For each layer, I have

`bert.encoder.layer.x.attention.self.*` (6 vectors)
`bert.encoder.layer.x.attention.output.*` (4 vectors)
`bert.encoder.layer.x.intermediate.dense.weight`
`bert.encoder.layer.x.intermediate.dense.bias`
`bert.encoder.layer.x.output.dense.weight`
`bert.encoder.layer.x.output.dense.bias`
`bert.encoder.layer.x.output.LayerNorm.weight`
`bert.encoder.layer.x.output.LayerNorm.bias`

Comment: The answer can be similar to this question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/62658/how-to-get-sentence-embedding-using-bert ...but any other information about the layer mentioned above is appreciated.

Comment: None of the `output.dense.weight, output.dense.bias, output.LayerNorm.weight output.LayerNorm.bias` is an "output".

Comment: If you want to use "output of the BERT model before the classifier layer" you have to do this in `forward` function. You don't really need to (and most of the time should not) change how you load the weight.

Comment: But you'll have to dig out how the `forward` of the `BERT` implementation you're using is written. Or specify which implementation it is.